# session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 97

Tags: java, selenium, maven, jenkins, testng

I am trying to run from CMD with mvn test some classes from selenium testng.

My chrome driver was last updeted to ver. 99 and from that point I got this error message in the CMD :

```
[ERROR] ShufersalMiron.Sprod.PInfo_Add_Delete_Address.initializeDriver  Time elapsed: 3.489 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 97
Current browser version is 99.0.4844.51 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

I can see a mismatch between the versions but what this sentence :
"This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 97" mean ? what is the meaning "This version" ?

Please help me solve it.